# VS 2019 with VB, creating an ADODB connection to a SQL Server DB

Tags: vb.net, adodb, visual-studio-2019

My searches with Bing and Google have been fruitless, I think probably due to the newness of my version of VS (2019). As mentioned in the title, I'm trying to create an ADODB connection to a SQL Server DB. In the past, all I've needed to do was add a reference to a "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects" library and then add code like:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "connection string"
```

In VS 2019, I'm not finding any ActiveX Data Objects libraries listed when I do an "Add Reference". Has anyone had a chance to do this in VS 2019 yet?

Comment: Going back to 2010 or earlier, I don't see how 2019 has changed. `Add Reference` ... `COM` ... `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using ADO.Net?  The code is almost the same and you can avoid a dependency on using a COM object.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway No reason other than I haven't used it before and right now, I'm working with what I know how to do. It's something I want to research when I have the time. Right now, I'm trying to convert 5 front ends from Access VBA to .Net ASAP. Once that's done, I can go back and figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a reference directly

- Add Reference

  - COM

    - Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library

Or you can find it on NuGet: **ADODB**

Comment: Ah, I'm used to it all being in one big list. The default was "Assemblies", never noticed "COM". Found it there. THANKS!

Comment: @PKatona *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library* is not a .NET assembly, it is a COM library. It has a corresponding Primary Interop Assembly, ADODB.dll, which .NET can interpret, and hides the integration between CLR and COM. For this reason, AXDO is (and has always been) under COM when adding a reference in .NET. VB6, by contrast, operates in COM so there would only be one big list when adding a reference in VB6.

Comment: That's right... I'd been doing only VB6 for the last 5 years, and hadn't created anything new in .Net in almost 10 years (only maintenance), so I no longer remembered anything with .Net. Using VB6 is what screwed me up. Again, THANKS!